# How to prevent foot odour or reduce the smell?

Tags: shoes, smell

I have a huge problem with my feet. when I put my foot in my shoes for 10 minutes my feet get a very bad smell that I can't even think about it. and if I go to school for 8 hrs, the smell will not free even with washing! my shoes have some hole for the air changing but that's not helping.
Thanks.

Comment: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7872/how-to-protect-your-shoes-from-bad-smell?rq=1 this is about how to protect but what if its already get bad smell?

Comment: Do you use socks?

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put the tea bags into the shoes on the night.
2. Wear socks made from natural materials.
3. Remove old skin from your feet.
4. Check your health, because this smell can be because of foot fungus or endocrine diseases.

Comment: Of course be sure to change your socks very frequently and wash your feet.

Comment: Bamboo fiber socks are antibacterial

Answer (score 0):

I use a hand shaker and sprinkle baking soda in my rain boots after wearing them. It's not foolproof, but seems to help.

Comment: Thanks but not rain boot!